# How to delay sencha view being loaded

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

After my application finished loading, i am displaying tab panel and the default first tab (first item in tab panel) will appear in screen.

```
        Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype : 'myTab'
    });
```

when the tab panel loads i am going to display set of message in first tab based on latitude and longitude.

i am getting latitude and longitude using phonegap at controller init method, controller init method is going to be called first before any thing else.

i am sending a ajax request to My server with latitude and longitude as param when first tab painting.

**my problem is phonegap taking some time give latitude and longitude, before i am getting latitude and longitude my view is pained and ajax request is happening.**

**so i can't able to send latitude and longitude as parameter with ajax request.**

How can i delay tab panel being pained for some time ?.

this is my phone gap code to get latitude and longitude  (at controller init method).

```
        var gotLocation = false;
    var GEO_OPTS = {
        enableHighAccuracy : true,
        maximumAge : 120000,
        timeout : 6000
    };
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        if (gotLocation)
            return;
        console.log('inside onsuccess');
        if (position.coords.accuracy <= 1000) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            console.log('Got location at end');
            gotLocation = true;
            // proceed to fetch messages
            var radius = localStorage.radius ? localStorage.radius : 5;

            console.log('radius :' + radius);
            var unit = localStorage.unit ? localStorage.unit : "M";
            var rangeText = ' ' + radius;
            if (unit == 'M')
                rangeText = rangeText + ' mi';
            else
                rangeText = rangeText + ' km';
            var listCaption = 'All wants within' + rangeText;

            localStorage.latitude = lat;
            localStorage.longitude = lon;
            localStorage.radius = radius;
            localStorage.unit = unit;
            localStorage.rangeText = rangeText;
            localStorage.listCation = listCaption;
            console.log('Range Text:' + rangeText);
            console.log('list Caption:' + listCaption);
        }
    };

    var onError = function (error) {
        navigator.notification
                .alert("oops..." + error.code + error.message);
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, GEO_OPTS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things
1. Add some delay to the code which add your tab panel to the viewport

```
Ext.defer(function(){ 
    Ext.Viewport.add({
      xtype : 'myTab'
    });
}, 500, this);
```

2. Add mytab in success handler function

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    /* All the existing code*/
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype : 'myTab'
    });
}
```